# Merge conflicts while trying to change author of the first commit with interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have a project with large number of commits (more than 1000) merged from different branches.
I need to change author's name of the first commit.

Tried to do it with

```
git rebase -i --root
```

Set "edit" near this commit.
Then used

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>
git rebase --continue
```

**And I get an unimaginable amount of merge conflicts... Too much to resolve them manually.**

The first error is (if resolve it I get similar errors after):

```
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
Could not apply a03a0ce1... master # Merge branch 'master' into 'dev'
```

Tried to use --rebase-merges flag but got the same result.

Does anybody know why it happens? Any other ways to solve?
Thanks!

Comment: You should have said `git rebase -i --root --keep-merges`. But even then you should expect merge conflicts, plus things will be insanely complicated and the computer will probably explode. Plus what's your plan if you ever succeed at this insane plan? You'll have to push with force and thus destroy the entire history for everyone else working on the project, and they won't be happy. Just leave the history alone, would be my advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email+multiple+commits

Comment: Yes, it's important for client, if I don'to do it, we'll need to clear all history by making a new project !)
Thanks for reply.

Comment: Since every single commit in your history will be replaced by this action, one way or another, you _are_ effectively clearing all history and making a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have problems in old commits.
Try this

git filter-branch command. It lets rewrite history, preserve all information (including original commit times or merge information)
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_NAME="wrong author"
NEW_NAME="correct author"
NEW_EMAIL="email@mail.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "$WRONG_NAME" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "$WRONG_NAME" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

(can use filter WRONG_NAME or WRONG_EMAIL here)

or this

Use a git-filter-repo tool https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

1. Install git-filter-repo
2. Create a fresh clone of your project.
3. Check email of invalid author with
   `git shortlog --email`
4. Create a file .mailmap with content
   `NewName <new-email-address@new.com> <old-mail@mail.ru>`
5. Command
   `git filter-repo --use-mailmap`

Comment: All very true, but rewriting deep history in a shared repo is still a terrible idea.

Comment: @matt it's really not that bad if you're working with people who know what they're doing. But when you're doing stuff on the internet, *then* you're in for fun.

Comment: @hobbs I still think, though, that no one who advises `filter-branch/repo` should omit the warning.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to change all mentions to a specific author (identified by a name or an email), you can go with [@RustyNail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73499439/86072).

---

If your intention is to modify just a single commit at the beginning of your history :

you can use the `git replace`/`git filter-repo --force` trick, mentionned in [`git-filter-repo`'s documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_parent_rewriting_2) :

> **Parent rewriting**
>
> To replace `$commit_A` with `$commit_B` (e.g. make all commits which had `$commit_A` as a parent instead have `$commit_B` for that parent), and rewrite history to make it permanent:
>
> ```
> git replace $commit_A $commit_B
> git filter-repo --force
> ```

In your case :

- create, as you did, a copy of the initial commit with the correct author:

```
git checkout <original-hash>
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"

# use 'git replace' to replace the old commit with the new one:
git replace <original-hash> HEAD
```

- run `git filter-repo --force`

---

The warning mentionned by @matt still holds : if your repository is shared with many users (e.g: your fellow developpers), it can be very tricky to have everyone sync their work correctly with the rewritten history.